# InetAddress.getByName extremely slow

Tags: java, linux, networking, centos

`InetAddress.getByName` seems to be really slow on my machine running CentOS 6. Java profiling shows it takes 4.9 seconds to complete.

The Linux 'dig' command however only takes 300ms to complete, which is normal.

4.9 seconds seems abnormally long, what could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with my DNS resolver. The server it was querying was being blocked my host's firewall.